# Pythonic way to split a string and unpack into variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Simple question: given a string

```
string = "Word1 Word2 Word3 ... WordN"
```

is there a pythonic way to do this?

```
firstWord = string.split(" ")[0]
otherWords = string.split(" ")[1:]
```

Like an unpacking or something?

Thank you

Comment: Sample code should be `otherWords = string.split(" ")[1:]`, right?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since Python 3 and [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), you can use extended unpacking.

This way, you can unpack arbitrary string containing any number of words. The first will be stored into the variable `first`, and the others will belong to the list (possibly empty) `others`.

```
first, *others = string.split()
```

Also, note that default delimiter for `.split()` is a space, so you do not need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: Adapting to the question's example, it'd be `firstWord, *otherWords = string.split()`

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed!
I'm using python 3 anyway.

Comment: Where does the third word go?

Comment: @Blender Indeed, my bad. Thank you.

Comment: @thn nowhere afaik

Comment: @thn About `first, second, *_ = string.split()`, the third word would go into the `_` variable which is used for discarded values.

Comment: @DanielSanchez Python 3 only, yes, thank you for the precision, I will add this to the answer.

Comment: @Delgan I see. Interesting to know about _.

Answer (score 7):

From [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

Many algorithms require splitting a sequence in a "first, rest" pair, if you're using Python2.x, you need to try this:

```
seq = string.split()
first, rest = seq[0], seq[1:]
```

and it is replaced by the cleaner and probably more efficient in `Python3.x`:

```
first, *rest = seq
```

For more complex unpacking patterns, the new syntax looks even cleaner, and the clumsy index handling is not necessary anymore.

Comment: I knew of the first one, which was kind of obvious, but it would imply splitting the string twice.

Comment: @ThomasKowalski you can split the string `seq= string.split()` and then use it.