# How to keep Python command line of your Programme running after executing a system/shell/OS command through your Programme

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, loops, cmd

Alright so I have made a Python Programme which is used to execute commands such as Date, Time, Log Off, etc.
It uses input from user to execute these commands using the command prompt(since I am using Windows), it may work similarly on Mac os or Kali shell.

So if user inputs a command like:

```
>>>date
```

The output will be something of this sort:

```
>>>The current date is: 12/18/19
```

the code used here is:

```
     input1=input("Your Input")
     if (input1=="date"):
     import os
     os.system('cmd /k "date"')
```

This, in the same window where Python is running( C:\Windows\py.exe ) gives the output of the date.

BUT

After this it gives the following:

```
The current date is: Wed 12/18/2019
Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

But I do not want this Programme to end after showing me the date, I want it to loop and ask me to input a command again. BUT even after using the:

```
while True:
```

Above, Module, it does not loop around and just gives this as the output after Date:

```
The current date is: Wed 12/18/2019
Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy)  #when you press the Enter key, you get the following:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Is there any solution to this? It would help me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Write a loop in the program.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to keep a Python script output window open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175800/pythonic-way-to-split-a-string-and-unpack-into-variables)

Answer (score 1):

```
while 1:
    input1=input("Your Input")
    if (input1=="date"):
        import os
        os.system('cmd /k "date"')
```

You could also add some logic to quit the program if the input is exit, for example, by using `break`.

**NOTE**: I do not recommend re-importing `os` inside loop, you can import it outside and just use `os.system`.

Comment: Thank You, I actually found another way, i.e. by using datetime module, I will try this out and tell you! :)