# Reading Multiple file in Python

Tags: python, sys

I am learning python and in as much as the learning process seems to be going on smoothly. I am practically stuck trying to open a set of files all with the same structure using sys.argv. I have the following code that I cant understand how to fix it in order to perform similar operations on all the files.

```
import sys
if __name__ =='__main__':
    year_name = sys.argv[1]
    filename = open('year_2011.txt','r').readlines()
    for line in filename:
       line=line.strip('\t') # *seperated by tabs*
        year,y,x, amt # *columns in each of the filenames*
        y = int(y)
        x = int(x)
        amt = float(amt)
```

each time I run the simple code I get the error "list index out of range" any help on how I can solve this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: you giving any arg in command line?

Comment: please provide the command you are running from the command line in order to invoke this. also what's the point of `year_name`? you never use that variable, it seems like you want to incorporate it as part of `filename` but haven't?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have 6 files all saved by their year name, so for instance the first file is year_2011. therefore in each command line argument i want to call each file using the respective year while performing the same task. would this be the right way to do it. Also am i defining the columns for the files correctly

Comment: Please show the command you are typing into the terminal. Also you should consider using the os module instead of the sys module since you already know where the files are

Comment: so I have done a bit of research and I have used os.chdir(path) to change the path at the terminal which worked well. I then call at the terminal using this command line argument. "python script.py year_2011" now getting a syntax error on the script

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question, especially if that data is from an external/unreachable resource.  the easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses.  In this case a few representative lines from a file - formatted as code. [mcve].

Comment: `# *seperated by tabs*` - yet you are using the `str.strip() method`. One nice thing about an interpreted language is you can test stuff out in the shell - have you tried `line.strip('\t')` in the shell with a representative line?

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Related [Pythonic way to split a string and unpack into variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175800/pythonic-way-to-split-a-string-and-unpack-into-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line under the `for` loop wasn't properly indented.  Also you were using `strip` instead of `split`.

```
import sys
if __name__ =='__main__':
    year_name = sys.argv[1]
    filename = open(year_name,'r').readlines()
    for line in filename:
        year, y, x, amt = line.split('\t') # *separated by tabs*
        y = int(y)
        x = int(x)
        amt = float(amt)
```

Comment: Regarding the input, you'll need to specify the full year_2011.txt rather than just year_2011.